# knitr + R3.0.0: error in sum(figs)

Tags: knitr, lyx

Since the upgrade of R (2.15.1>3.0.0) I get an error when using knitr on file.Rhtml and also with Lyx.
The version of knitr is 1.1.

The error message is :

```
Erreur dans sum(figs) : 'type' (list) de l'argument incorrect
Calls: knit ... <Anonymous> -> process_group.block -> call_block -> block_exec
```

Any idea to solve this?

Alain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: knitr 1.2 is on [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/package=knitr) now, in which this problem was fixed.

---

I think I have fixed this problem in the [development version](https://github.com/yihui/knitr#readme), which will be on CRAN soon. For now, please try

```
install.packages('knitr', repos = 'http://www.rforge.net/', type = 'source')
```